# Azure ApplicationInsights Web custom events

Tags: web, azure-application-insights

I am trying to setup azure applicationinsights for my SPA app.

Additionaly to default metrics I wan't to log some custom things like in this example: resolution and tenant name.

Event seems to be send correctly however in azure portal I see these values as undefined:

[image]

What should I configure to have these values visible?

```
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';

const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey,
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true
    }
});

appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView();
appInsights.trackEvent({
    name: "Resolution",
    properties: {
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        tenant: 'some tenant name'
    },
});
```

Comment: Any progress sir? Hope it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me sir, could you pls add more details on your problem?

I added app sights in my react app, and I found it's ok to see the custom events in log query.

[image]
[image]